# how to remove the search bar for emoji-mart emoji picker?

Tags: node.js, npm, emoji, ngx-emoji-mart

https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-mart

I am using the above NPM package to implement an emoji picker. The search bar is superfluous.

How do I remove it?

Answer (score 1):

The docs have a big section on the options you can pass in, and one of them is `navPosition`, which is `top`, `bottom`, or `none`. Make it `none` and it should go away.

Comment: The `navPosition=none` removes the top navigators, not the search bar

Comment: actually, i found it. It is `searchPosition=none`